# Zynq Ultrascale+ MPSoC VCU TRD 2018.1 SD Card Boot Error

Tags: sd-card

I am really new in Ubuntu, I want to implement Zynq Ultrascale MPSoc VCU TRD 2018.1 Design Module-2 application on Zcu106 rev 1.0 Board. I installed petalinux 2018.1, I created the BOOT image , copy all the files from the $TRD_HOME/images/sdirx-vcu-sditx/ to SD card directory.

However when I insert the SD Card, I set the SW6 switches as 0111 and tried to start Zynq I just got this message on Teraterm Screen:

Xilinx Zynq MP First Stage Boot Loader
Release 2018.1 May 8 2018 - 12:21:51

In reference design page it said :

```
Power on the board; make sure INIT_B, done and all power rail LEDs are lit green.
```

At first INIT_B is red,after a few seconds it turns green,

done LED which behind the INIT_B is never light up,

and after a while INIT_B turns red and PS_ERR_STAT led also lit red.

I saw the similar problems in website but either their design structures were different from mine, or their problems were still unresolved.

I changed the DRAM settings according to this page:

https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/71961.html

and made all project again and create another BOOT file but when I tried it, it's still not working ( works exactly the same as before.)

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.